# Swing - Android like Drop-Down-Menu

Tags: java, swing, drop-down-menu

How can i realize this Android-Drop-Down-Menu in Java-Swing? I can only find tutorials for Android (with XML-Layout) but nothing for Swing.

Screenshot:

[image: http://www11.pic-upload.de/16.01.15/15s13n8z9jw.png]

I already have this code:

```
JMenu menu = new JMenu();
        BufferedImage image = null;
        try {

            image = ImageIO.read(new URL("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/very-basic-android-l-lollipop-icon-pack/24/menu2-32.png"));

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        menu.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        menuBar.setBorderPainted(false);
        menuBar.add(menu);

        JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem("Test Item");
        item.setBorderPainted(false);
        item.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        menu.add(item);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setSize(500, 550);

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.add(menuBar);
        frame.add(panel_1);

        frame.setVisible(true);
```

But as you can see it doesn't look exactly like in the Screenshot:

[image: http://www11.pic-upload.de/16.01.15/n7536l3voi1s.jpg]

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Comment: Android does not have Swing... I'm I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're just looking for the JCheckBoxMenuItem.  You can add it to any JMenu. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JCheckBoxMenuItem.html

(If I understood your question correctly then you already have this implemented in Android and are interested in porting it to a Swing application).

Comment: 1+ for the JCheckBoxMenuItem. I would start by reading the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) for a working example of using a JCheckBoxMenuItem.

Comment: No, sorry for my bad explainitation, but i wether have the android-code, nor the swing code. But i'm searching for the swing-code. Take a look at my editted Topic-Text for further information. Thank you

Comment: Where you are creating a JMenuItem you should be creating a JCheckBoxMenuItem.  This is what will make the check show up.  You might want to experiment with different look & feels, too.